# Django, where to update failed login attempts and why?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have a custom user model where I want to track number of failed login attempts and take action based on that. I am wondering what would be a better place to write this logic.

Following are two options I have in mind for updating *failed_attempts* field in User model:

1. Autheticate method in the backend.
2. *check_password* method in the User model. I have overridden this method from AbstractBaseUser model.

And the basic logic(does not cover all cases) is like this:

- If authentication fails check the time of previous failed login attempt.
- If that was recent, increment failed login count.
- If count reaches maximum attempt lock the account for few minutes (or do something else).

My question is what would be a better place for writing this logic and why.

Comment: I am not sure that you must persist the failed attempts. Maybe store it is enough to store it in the session?

Comment: You could just use [django-axes](http://code.google.com/p/django-axes). I've used it for a few projects and it works well.

Comment: @miku: You wouldn't want to store it in the session. Any brute force attack wouldn't respect session cookies.

Comment: @dgel: No I wouldn't do that if it were security related, but if it's just for something like a "Did you forget your password?" link, then it's probably ok. For security related stuff I'd probably use something outside of Django.

Comment: @miku it is actually for security. Just to put a threshold in case account hacking is attempted.

Comment: If want to go in the direction of IP-banning and such you could write a log file of failed attempts and then let this nice project take care of the rest: https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban

Comment: @miku that's a good option to keep in mind. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only the details you list, I would say the Authentication method is more appropriate, if only because it would be **very** confusing if `check_password` updates fields on the model.

Why, though, do you have both an 'Authenticate method in the backed' and a `check_password` method in the model?

Comment: check_password method is defined in AbstractBaseUser model, Django's base auth model. You have a good point about check_password updating a field, that is indeed confusing.

Comment: Does your `check_password` actually do anything, though? If so, it's not clear whose responsibility it is to actually determine when a login attempt failed.

Comment: Here is the original method: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L237 I was thinking to override this just to check & update failed attempts. But just on the basis of your point about confusion I think I want to avoid using that method to write my logic.

Comment: I would strongly encourage you not to alter check_password, as doing so can offer a timing attack, giving an attacker clues about whether they are making progress on the correct password.  Django goes to some effort to avoid this path of attack: https://github.com/django/django/blob/f5e9d67907/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L100

For this specific idea, I'd recommend you dispatch an async job (regardless of correctness) and in that async job do whatever you need to note failures.

Answer (score 1):

**What:** I would actually implement that logic in an Authentication Backend.

**How:** Use a specific, separate, Model to track login attempts, or, use the solution suggested by miko (fail2ban).

**Why:** You de-couple authentication from users. Bonus: if you want to take advantage of the upcoming pluggable `User` models in Django, that's a good idea.

---

On a side note, there probably is a way you can achieve an even "neater" solution by wrapping existing authentication backends to provide the required functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Thomas. I am actually using a custom User model and i have failed_attempts and last_failed_at fields defined in this model. I also have a custom Authentication backend. So it is easier for me to add this in Authenticate method.